# How to debug async functions using Chrome?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, google-chrome-devtools

Take a look at the following code

```
async function example () {
  const a = await resolveAfter2Secs(20);
  const b = await resolveAfter4Secs(30);
  return a + b;
}
```

Is there a recommended standard way to debug this using Chrome dev tools? I've read about some options using Canary, but I'm looking for anything similar in Chrome.

Is there currently a way to enable async call stack feature in Chrome?

Comment: It's enabled by default. As long as your source mapping is right it should work.

Comment: @CamilleWintz: Chrome supports `async` without transpiling.

Comment: Rohit, it's not clear what you're asking here. If I debug that code with an up-to-date version of Chrome, I can step through `example`, see the stack (for instance, if I use another async function to call it), etc. What exactly are you seeing and what would you like to see instead?

Comment: in chrome version 70.0 I can write in devtools `await Promise.resolve(1)` and result will be `1`